# What’s the name of this tree?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I’m trying to find information about this tree that I didn’t plant. Looking for information in terms of pruning, etc.
[image]

It had white flowers on it this spring, but is now flower less and has very few young berry-esque type fruits growing on it. They’re very small still, but it seems they’re going from green to a red. This in Michigan.

Additional pictures:
[image]
[image]

Thanks to Bryan Hanson for the answer! Found a picture online of it with flowers: [image]

Comment: Where is this plant located?

Comment: Could you please add close-ups of the leaves, flowers and fruits?

Comment: @Chris Michigan. Sorry I should have included that in OP. I will upload closer pictures sometime today when I return home.

Comment: @Taskle please [edit] your own post to include your location as well as additional close-up images of the leaves and fruit. The more detail the better!

Comment: I've added additional pictures, with closeups on the leaves as well as one of the fruits. I can really only count 2-3 fruits growing as of right now on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Revised Answer

The additional pictures point to something in the genus *Prunus*.  Note that there are extrafloral nectaries at the base of the leaves, and feathery stipules are visible (see [here](https://oregonstate.edu/dept/ldplants/pracc11.htm) for annotated picture of a different species).  Since it has a weeping habit, and doubly toothed leaves, I think what you have there might be a Japanese Weeping Cherry *Prunus subhirtella* var. pendula (but other names seem to be in use).  Some info [here](http://www.hort.uconn.edu/plants/detail.php?pid=363) which seems consistent with your specimen.

### Original Incorrect Answer

I think you are probably looking at *Ulmus glabra* "Camperdownii" or a similar cultivar.  This is a "weeping" elm variety that is produced by grafting; all plants are descendants of a single tree. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulmus_glabra_%27Camperdownii%27) gives the full background.  Your specimen has somewhat more pointy leaves than many of the images for Camperdown Elm I found online, but apparently there can be some variation.

EDIT: The fruit picture (added after my answer) clearly rules out my answer!  Also looks like there are nectaries at the base of the leaves.

Comment: The Japanese Weeping Cherry is definitely it. I found some pictures online and the “snow” colored flowers are a perfect match as to what it looked like back in April.